# Servicing 2 stroke line trimmer

Tags: maintenance

I have a 4 year old 2 stroke line trimmer (Husqvarna 524L) which is working beautifully but has never been taken back to the store for a service. I have washed the filters a couple of times, but done no other maintenance I am not particularly knowledgeable about gas engines)

Labour is very expensive where I live in NZ but thanks to parellel imports and few.import taxes hardware is fairly cheap.

Getting the trimmer serviced will cost about 1/4 of the value of a new machine. How stupid would ot be to NOT get it serviced and wait for it to break or act up before getting it looked at (and if to expensive to fix simply replace)?

Other then cleaning/replacing the filters is there any simple maintenance I should be doing?

Comment: Does "cleaning the filters" include cleaning the spark suppressor screen in the exhaust?

Comment: I dont think so. I dont understand what you are saying. Ill look into what this is. Thank you.

Comment: Most/all trimmers have a (literal) screen in the exhaust port, to prevent 'sparks' from starting brush fires.  It can get fouled with oil, esp if you run at part throttle.  If it does, you'll know - the engine will run poorly or not at all.  So, you can just check it then, if that happens.  It was probably a silly thing to bring up.

Comment: Replacing the spark plug is about the only other thing needed. Make sure the gap is of the proper size. The old plug over many hours of use will either build deposits or the gap will burn larger than the specs call for.